# FOR XML in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, xml

I have this file output from sql server:

```
<ProductList>    
<Product>
  <Product_Department>Sales</Product_Department>
  <Product_Category>A</Product_Category>
  <Code>AA</Code>
  <Description>AAA</Description>
  <Price>10</Price>
</Product>
.
.
.
<Product>
.
.
.
</Product>
</ProductList>
```

The sql script is:

```
create proc xmlcollection
as
declare @XmlOutput xml 
set @XmlOutput = (select * from Product
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('ProductList'), ELEMENTS)
select @XmlOutput
go
```

The desired output of xml file would be:

```
<ProductList>
<Product DEP="Sales" CAT="A" CODE="AA" PRICE="10"></Product>
<Product.........................................></Product>
.
.
.
</ProductList>
```

How can I do that from FOR XML clause? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use '@' to specify attribute values when using FOR XML.

See below:

```
SELECT
     Product_Department AS '@DEP'
    ,Product_Category AS '@CAT'
    ,Code AS '@Code'
    ,[Description] AS '@DESC'
    ,Price AS '@PRICE'
FROM Product
FOR XML PATH ('Product'), ROOT ('ProductList')
```

As mentioned below, alternatively you could also use 'Type':

```
SELECT
     Product_Department AS 'DEP'
    ,Product_Category AS 'CAT'
    ,Code AS 'CODE'
    ,[Description] AS 'DESC'
    ,Price AS 'PRICE'
FROM Product
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ROOT('ProductList')
```

This will return the following XML:

```
<ProductList>
  <Product DEP="Sales" CAT="A" CODE="AA" DESC="AAA" PRICE="10" />
  <Product DEP="Marketing" CAT="B" CODE="MM" DESC="BBB" PRICE="15" />
</ProductList>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Or you can specify `FOR XML AUTO, TYPE`

Comment: so sweet. You are my personal jesus. I think I will be able to figure how to format a complex XML output now. Thx!!!!